# JQuery FadeOut happening at the wrong time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fadeout

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#full-btns").children().delay(4000).fadeOut("slow");

$('#full-btns').hover(function() {
      $('#full-btns').children().stop().animate({opacity:'100'});
      $('#full-btns').children().show();

}, function() {
        $("#full-btns").children().fadeOut("slow");

});
```

When the page is loaded, the `#full-btns` element is shown for 4000ms before fading out. The problem I have is that if a user hovers over the `#full-btns` element while its still visible, it causes it to fade out because `$("#full-btns").children().fadeOut("slow");` is called on the hover. I want `#full-btns` to always be visible when hovering over it.

When the page loads, hover over the red div, notice how it fades out. That is undesirable. When hovering over the red div (while its visible) it should remain visible

Update:
http://jsfiddle.net/gazedge/nhBBc/ (now includes solution)

Comment: The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

Comment: Could you show HTML along with the JS?

Comment: Do you really need to see the html? Its just a div with some buttons in...

Comment: The comment above is from jQuery's .delay() documentation.  So it doesn't matter if you have a stop() in there.  It will still fadeOut regardless since you are using .delay().  Have you thought about using setTimeout() instead?  That way you can cancel the timeout with clearTimeout()

Comment: @wirey thanks i will try that. I think there is another issue though, the hover caused the .fadeout to be called in the hover function - see update to question

Comment: @Gaz_Edge I guess I'm a little confused.  Are you able to create a jsfiddle.net?  Or your HTML structure would be really helpful.  I was trying to create a jsfiddle but I'm not entirely sure where your problem is http://jsfiddle.net/g8p39/

Comment: see update. When the page loads, hover over the red div, notice how it fades out. That is undesirable. When hovering over the red div (while its visible) it should remain visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use setInterval and clearInterval;

```
$('#full-btns').hover(function() {

      clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);        
      $('#full-btns').children().stop().animate({opacity:'100'});
      $('#full-btns').children().show();

}, function() { 
        $("#full-btns").children().fadeOut("slow");            
});

var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function() {
     $("#full-btns").children().fadeOut("slow");
}, 4000);
```

​

Answer (score 0):

If I haven't misunderstood the question - can't you just `return false;` at the end of your hover calls to prevent the events bubbling?

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html
http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Comment: thanks for the answer - im not sure that will fix my problem though. See my update for jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you have to do is clear all animation before anyone hovers.

```
$("#full-btns").children().delay(4000).fadeOut("slow");

    $('#full-btns').hover(function() {
        $('#full-btns').children().stop(true, true);  // Stop the fade-out animation
          $('#full-btns').children().stop().animate({opacity:'100'});
          $('#full-btns').children().show();

    }, function() {
        console.log('fadeOout called');
            $("#full-btns").children().fadeOut("slow"); 


    });​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nhBBc/5/

**Note:**  First time when you hover and (in your code) the div fades out it is not because of             **$("#full-btns").children().fadeOut("slow");** but because it is just completing the earlier animation which you have applied. [ your 1st line ].

Comment: May be I didn't understood the question properly. But to me http://jsfiddle.net/nhBBc/5/ [ *My Code* ]  and http://jsfiddle.net/gazedge/nhBBc/  [ *CORRECT answer* ] gave me the same results. Anyways thanx.